# Select IDs from R object

Tags: r

I have an R object that I load into R with one column per ID. 
My second file is a .txt file that I load in using `read.table()`. Here the ID number is listed in column 1 (eg one row per ID).

To do my analysis I need to create a new R object that only contains the IDs listed in the .txt file. Is there any command to create a new .Robj containing this subset of IDs?

I want to run this code:

```
norm.beta <- norm.beta[, colnames(norm.beta) %in% rownames(phen)]
phen <- phen[match(colnames(norm.beta), rownames(phen)), , drop=FALSE]
stopifnot(identical(rownames(phen), colnames(norm.beta)))
```

But the R object `norm.beta` has more IDs that the `phen` file

The norm.beta file has one column per ID and the variables underneath:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

x y z a b c d e f g
```

The phen file has the IDs in colum one:

```
2 a

4 b 

5 c 

6 d 

7 e
```

I want a new norm.beta file, but only with the IDs available in the phen file:

```
2 4 5 6 7 

y a b c d
```

Comment: I believe you want to do a "merge/ join (left or right join)". Without data we cannot help you. search for those above terms here on this site and add the tag --> `[r]` to it. So for e.g. "left join [r]". Good luck

Comment: I dont want to join I want to create a new Robj only containing the IDs that is in the txt file. I've added the code I want to run in the question

Comment: please take the time to make a little example of  `norm.beta` and `phen`. With `reproducible data` and `desired outcome`

Comment: I've tried to add it in the main text, I'm not sure how I can attach example files

Comment: hmm .. `norm.beta <- norm.beta[, colnames(norm.beta) %in% rownames(phen)]` should aquire exactly that.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I get an error saying identical(rownames(phen), colnames(norm.beta)) is not TRUE

Comment: try `all(sort(rownames(phen)) == sort(colnames(norm.beta)))`

Comment: Thanks, this doesnt seems to work. I get a matrix stating FALSE FALSE FALSE etc... and a warning message stating in sort(rownames(phen)) == sort(colnames(norm.beta)) longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: a matrix??? this should give you a vector.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I ment to say. a vector